# Remove duplicates algorithm, in place and stable (javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, duplicates

In class today we were asked to write an algorithm.

Given an array, remove duplicate values:

- It should be stable, and shouldn't have to use an inner loop.
- Should be done in place, as best as possible
- No use of built in functions (I was only allowed to use `.push`)

After wrestling with it for a while, this is what I came up with.

```
function remove_dupes(arr){
  var seen = {};
  var count = 0;

  for( var i = 0; i < arr.length - count ; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i+count];

    if( seen[arr[i]] ) {
      count++;
      arr[i] = arr[i+count];
      i--;
    }

    seen[arr[i]] = true;
  }

  arr.length = arr.length - count;
}
```

[Working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nisugahequ/edit?js,console)

I have a bit of repeated code here and I feel that maybe the `i--` isn't the best way to go.

Is there any way I could improve this code (without using built in functions)?

Comment: I actually think the code looks pretty good as written.  It's hard to write in-place code that looks anywhere near as neat as solutions that work on immutable objects.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I'm pretty early in my course so they're drilling the basics/fundamentals as much as possible into us.  My intuition hasn't developed to a point where I can look at something and know if it's an optimal solution on my own, so SO has been a great help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I think I got what you want without creating a new array:

```js
function remove_dupes(arr){
  var seen = {};
  
  var k = 0;
  for( var i=0; i<arr.length ;i++) {
    if( !seen[arr[i]] ) {
      arr[k++] = arr[i];
      seen[arr[i]] = 'seen';
    }
  }
  
  arr.length = k;
}


var x = [ 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 'dojo', 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 'dojo', 11 ];
remove_dupes(x);


document.write(x);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this solution is great, I'm going to accept this is as the answer

Comment: `arr.length = k;` is a nice touch _crying for documentation_.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a simpler solution to me:

```
function remove_dupes(arr){
  var seen = {};
  var dupes_removed = [];

  for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!seen[arr[i]]) {
      dupes_removed.push(arr[i]);
      seen[arr[i]] = true;
    }
  }

  return dupes_removed;
}
```

This runs in somewhere between O(n) and O(nlogn) time (because JS hash lookups are between O(1) and O(logn) time). This also guarantees the result will be stable. The other solutions so far either run in O(n^2) or aren't stable.

Comment: However, this solution isn't in place as the question requires.  It creates a new array.

Comment: Yes, what @ivern said.  I like the cleanliness of this code but for class we were asked not to create a new array.  Could you modify your solution to do it in place as much as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf to see if that value exists in arr than push to a new one

```js
function remove_dupes(arr){
  var newArr = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
    if(newArr.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1){
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return newArr;
}

var myArr = [2,4,2,4,6,6,6,2,2,1,10,33,3,4,4,4];

console.log(remove_dupes(myArr));
```

Comment: Nice clean solution but I was challenged not to create an array to return and couldn't use functions like indexOf. I had to do it in place as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to change the array in place ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/rpt72qqz/) - look at the console):

```
var arr = [1, 54, 5, 3, 1, 5, 20, 1, 54, 54];

var seen = {};

var length = arr.length;

var i = 0;

while (i < length) {
    if (seen[arr[i]] !== undefined) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        length--;
    } else {
        seen[arr[i]] = true;
    }

    i++;
}

console.log(arr);
```

This is O(n^2) as splice is O(n), and we iterate n elements.

Comment: I had done something like this originally using splice but my instructor challenged me to not use any built in functions so I was forced to go a different route

Comment: No problems, just add it to the question.

Comment: I mentioned it in the last line of the question, but that should be more visible, you're right. I'll make the edit

Comment: No my bad.  Definitely helps the question to be more clear about it upfront and keep all of the requirements in one place.  Still learning my way around SO, appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

This is a compact solution I am using in my JS array subclass:

```
if ( !Array.unique )
{
    Array.prototype.unique = function()
    {
        var tmp = {}, out = [], _i, _n ;
        for( _i = 0, _n = this.length; _i < _n; ++_i )
        if(!tmp[this[_i]]) { tmp[this[_i]] = true; out.push(this[_i]); }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is creating a new array and returning it isn't it? As I'm reading it, this isn't doing it in place

Comment: Do you mean to 'use the same working array' with 'in place' ?
Well, if so you might want to scan each element, check the array through .indexOf and, via .splice, remove the first indexed element each time .indexOf does not return -1 ... that's the basic idea, which has been already shown above

Comment: Correct.  Same array.  However, as stated in my question, I was not supposed to use any built in functions such as splice or indexOf.  That was part of the challenege

Comment: Well, this sounds just like an exercise. Anyway, how to remove duplicates without "splicing" the array ?

Comment: The approach that I took (and the approach of the answer I accepted) is basically to move all unique elements to the front of the array, and move the duplicates to the end of the array.  With a counter you know which index divides the uniques and dupes, so just truncate the array at that point.

Comment: You might want also to benchmark this approach with those reported here and see what runs faster. You might be good in coding yours, but if it runs slower, then you missed the point. So first generate an array of,10000 random entries between 1 and 10. Then take the unixtime elapse for both approaches.